# más/menos como preposición

Tags: preposiciones, acentuación

Desde hace tiempo, pienso que el «más» operador matemático debería escribirse sin acento diacrítico. Lo digo por las siguientes razones:

1. Se pronuncia casi siempre sin acento fonético: Véase 'En cuanto a manzanas, con las mías tenemos tres más cuatro que ha traído Juan' (más se pronuncia átono), mientras que «En cuanto a manzanas, yo tengo tres más que Juan» (el determinante «más» se pronuncia tónico).
2. Semánticamente tiene un papel muy semejante a la preposición «con» y análogo a las preposiciones «por» y «entre» que se usan en las operaciones multiplicación y división. Por tanto, por qué no es una preposición más (entonces también menos debería serlo; aunque entiendo que ello obligaría a plantearse la introducción de otras como módulo etc.)?

¿Alguien puede darme una justificación de ese acento? Diferenciarlo del «mas conjuntivo» no parece razón suficiente, ya que también está el determinante «más».

Comment: Interesante!!.  ..

Comment: La justificación de Fundéu es que solo hay dos clases y hay que ponerle tilde a una para diferenciarlo de la otra. https://www.fundeu.es/dudas/palabra-clave/mas-y-mas/#:~:text=La%20palabra%20mas%20solo%20se,la%20lengua%20espa%C3%B1ola%2C...

Comment: Entiendo que esa es la explicación estándar (en el colegio, creo recordar que ya se explicaba así). Sin embargo, pienso que su función como operador no es comparable a la de determinante, tal como he tratado de poner de manifiesto en los ejemplos. Otro sería: 'dos más dos es más que tres', en donde el primer más y el segundo tienen funciones (y pronunciaciones) marcadamente distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debemos entender que, si bien existe cierta relación entre la acentuación diacrítica y la pronunciación (el afirmativo *sí* es más fuerte que el condicional *si*), en última instancia se trata de una convención de la lengua, como ocurre con la decisión de la RAE de no exigir la tilde en los pronombres demostrativos (cuando claramente se pronuncian con más fuerza que los adjetivos demostrativos).

Por lo general se acentuará con tilde la palabra que sea de clase más abierta (verbos, sustantivos, adverbios) en detrimentro de la que sea de clase más cerrada (preposiciones, conjunciones, artículos). El caso de los pronombres es particular: cuando funciona como sujeto puede llevar acentro diacrítico para diferenciarse del artículo (*él* vs. *el*), pero en otros casos no lleva acento porque hay una palabra más rica semánticamente (*te* vs. *té*, o *se* vs. *sé*).

El caso de la conjunción copulativa *más* y de la conjunción adversativa *mas* es particular, tal vez el único donde dos palabras de la misma categoría gramatical no comparten la tilde. Tampoco creo que *más* en *cinco más tres* suene notoriamente más fuerte que *mas* en *cinco(,) mas tres* (aunque luego de la coma la conjunción adversativa suena algo más débil).

No obstante, inclusive en este caso creo que la tilde cumple su función diferenciadora. Imaginemos estos dos ejemplos (el primero tal vez sea un poco forzado pero creo que sirve para mi demostración):

(1)

A. ¿Cuántas manzanas y naranjas hay? ¿Están todas buenas?
B. Cinco (manzanas) **más** tres (naranjas) están en mal estado.

(2)

A. ¿Cuántas manzanas y naranjas hay? ¿Están todas buenas?
B. Cinco (manzanas y naranjas)(,) **mas** tres están en mal estado.

Para una descripción completa de las distintas categorías gramaticales de la palabra "más", ver [este artículo](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/M%C3%A1s-adverbio-adjetivo-pronombre.htm#:%7E:text=M%C3%A1s%20puede%20ser%20adverbio%20comparativo,Habla%20m%C3%A1s%20alto.&text=Tambi%C3%A9n%20puede%20funcionar%20como%20adjetivo,Han%20llegado%20m%C3%A1s%20invitados.).

Comment: Gracias. El ejemplo muestra cómo tilde deshace la ambigüedad en caso de obviar la coma, pero no estoy seguro de que evitar los rarísimos casos que puedan generarla justifique la excepción. Dicho esto, la interpretación del <<más>> operativo como una conjunción también es problemática, ya que la conjunción pone a los dos elementos al mismo nivel, mientras que la operación matemática los combina produciendo un resultado al que implícitamente nos referimos (ej: 'dos entre tres').

Comment: Es obvio que todo es cuestión de convención, pero igualmente pienso que la citada omisión de la tilde en los pronombres demostrativos es perniciosa y, de hecho, dificulta la lectura de forma notable.

Answer (score 1):

La razón es para distinguirlo de la **conjunción adversativa** *mas*, que se escribe sin tilde.

Es la misma razón por la que se escribe *sé* (de saber), y *se* (pronombre reflexivo), o *dé* (del verbo dar) y *de* (preposición).

Comment: Gracias. Como he comentado al final de mi pregunta que esa no me parece razón de suficiente peso, ya que también hay que distinguirlo del determinante más.

Comment: Lo mismo dice Fundéu. https://www.fundeu.es/dudas/palabra-clave/mas-y-mas/#:~:text=La%20palabra%20mas%20solo%20se,la%20lengua%20espa%C3%B1ola%2C...