# Si "más" y "mas" tienen la misma etimología, ¿cómo, y en qué orden, surgieron sus significados aparentemente opuestos?

Tags: etimología, historia, conjunciones

Tras leer [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35578/24236), me surgió la duda de por qué "más" y "mas" tienen significados aparentemente opuestos ("más" indica adición, mientras que "mas" indica contraposición)<sup>1</sup>. Sorprendentemente (para mí), tanto [el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/mas) como [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?mas) afirman que "mas" (con significado adversativo) viene de "más" (con significado aditivo). Esto me resulta aún más sorprendente al ver que en francés e italiano existe solo la versión adversativa:

- Francés: *[mais](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mais/48716)*, que parece equivalente a *pero* o *mas* en español
- Italiano: *[ma](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/ma_1.shtml)*, que significa *pero*. O *[mai](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/mai.shtml)*, que significa *nunca*.

Si nos fiamos de [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mas%2Cm%C3%A1s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true#), parece ser que en el pasado, "mas" (adversativo) era mucho más común que "más" (aditivo)<sup>2</sup>. Pero la tendencia se invirtió entre 1860 y 1900, y ahora la versión aditiva "más" es mucho más común que la versión adversativa "mas".

Parece entonces haber una contradicción entre lo que dicen el DLE y Etimologías de Chile (que "mas" viene de "más") y lo que vemos en el francés, italiano, y en español por vía de Google Ngrams (que parecen indicar que "mas" vino antes).

¿Hay algún estudio sobre el tema? ¿Cuál de los dos significados es anterior? ¿Por qué evolucionó esta palabra a tener un significado aparentemente opuesto?

**Pregunta extra (bonus):** ¿había en español una conjunción distinta de "más" para expresar adición antes de 1800?

---

<sup>1</sup>Sé que los significados no son *exactamente* opuestos, dado que el opuesto *exacto* de "más" es "menos". Pero la adición y la contraposición son *de algún modo* opuestos. Para los puristas, se podría decir que son *completamente diferentes*, o incluso *muy diferentes*: la pregunta seguiría siendo válida.




<sup>2</sup> Estoy dando por supuesto que "más" y "mas" tenían los mismos significados en 1800 que ahora, y que Google Ngrams es capaz de distinguir correctamente las versiones con o sin tilde.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que antiguamente los diccionarios no distinguían entre _mas_ y _más_, tanto el _Covarrubias_ (1611) como el _Autoridades_ (1734) solo recogen _mas_, de ahí que esta forma ganara por goleada en tiempos remotos. El primer diccionario de la RAE que recoge ambas formas fue la edición del DLE de 1869, lo cual coincide con la inversión de la tendencia que comentas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pregunta resulta muy interesante, pero va a ser complicado dar una respuesta, porque parece que ambos significados de *mas* se han usado desde siempre. Ya en diccionarios antiguos como el Casas de 1570 o el Percival de 1591 recogen ambos usos a la hora de traducir la palabra al italiano y al inglés, respectivamente. Pero vámonos aun más atrás. En el castellano medieval se pueden ver ambas formas, por ejemplo, en el texto *Fueros de Medinaceli*, de 1129 aproximadamente. Expongo a continuación dos casos:

> *Muler qui provada fuere por mala, si á varon ó á mulier denostrare, denle muchas feridas sin calonia, si provar ielo podieron, mas non la maten, nin la lisien.*
>
> *Cuyo parient matare, si vecino fuere de la vila, el parient fuere mas cercano desafie por si et por todos sus parientes.*

Se ve claramente que en el primer caso *mas* equivale a *pero*, mientras que en el segundo caso hace de adverbio comparativo (el pariente más cercano). El caso más antiguo que he encontrado es el siguiente:

> *Et por que este preujllejo sea mas fyrme mande le sellar con mjo sello de cera.*
>
> Anónimo, "Carta de Alfonso VI sobre las heredades del Cid", 1075 (España).

No encuentro casos más antiguos de *mas* como *pero* que el expuesto arriba, ni tampoco de *maes* que sería la forma anterior. En todo caso con estos datos no puedo llegar a ninguna conclusión, así que toca tirar de Corominas. En su diccionario etimológico se puede leer lo siguiente:

> Con el valor de conjunción adversativa, *magis* apareció ya en latín vulgar, donde primeramente servía para agregar una circunstancia nueva, con el valor de 'hay más', 'es más', y después pasó a emplearse como hecho alegado en oposición a lo anterior.

Así que parece que, efectivamente, el uso de *mas* con ambos significados ha estado en la lengua española desde sus orígenes, y que hay que buscar los orígenes de dichos usos en el latín vulgar, hablado con anterioridad al siglo IX. Y como respuesta, parece que su uso como adición fue anterior al de contraposición.